# Make a program (written in Golang) use one of the two available IP addresses

Tags: go, server, plesk

In one Server, I have two IP adresses. I can easily say wich domain uses wich IP Address using Plesk but, I have another program I wrote on Go which crawls some websites and it's not using any particular domain for that. How can I make that programm use one of the two IPs I have?

EDIT: what I want is to dial from a particular Address

Comment: What do you want it to choose the IP address for? Do you want to listen in a particular address? Do you want to Dial from a particular address?

Comment: I want to Dial from a particular address. The crawler should do the requests it does from a particular address.